# Django 1.7.2 migration changes continuously detected

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Below I have model that seems to continuously detect altered changes when running `makemigrations`. This was not the case in Django 1.6.4 with South.

Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied. 
Run `manage.py makemigrations` to make new migrations, and then re-run `manage.py migrate` to apply them.

Model:

```
class Item (models.Model):
    capacity = models.IntegerField(
        default=500,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
        help_text="Total remaining quantity in stock."
    )
    total_purchased = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(capacity)],
        help_text="Total items purchased."
    )
```

I solved this by commenting out the validators attribute for the total_purchased field. Is there any way around this issue without removing the validator while still being able to reference the previous field "capacity" in the "total_purchased" validator? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to `capacity` in the validator in this way. The `MaxValueValidator` is instantiated when models.py is loaded, not when a particular item is validated -- `capacity` is the model field, not the capacity of a particular item.

It isn't possible to access the values of other fields from inside a validator. When you need to perform validation that relies on multiple fields, you can create a custom [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method:

```
class Item (models.Model):
    capacity = models.IntegerField(
        default=500,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
        help_text="Total remaining quantity in stock."
    )
    total_purchased = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        help_text="Total items purchased."
    )

    def clean(self):
        """
        Ensures that total_purchased does not exceed the capacity
        """
        if self.total_purchased > self.capacity:
            raise ValidationError(
                'Total purchased can not exceed the capacity'
            )
```